# Unicode Error when extracting XML file Python

Tags: python, xml, unicode

```
import os, csv, io

from xml.etree import ElementTree
file_name = "example.xml"
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("xml", file_name))
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
Fruit = dom.findall("Fruit")

with io.open('test.csv','w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for f in Fruit:
        Explanation = f.findtext("Explanation")
        Types = f.findall("Type")
        for t in Types:
            Type = t.text
            a.writerow([Type, Explanation])
```

I am extracting data from a XML file, and put it into a CSV file. I am getting this error message below. It is probably because the extracted data contains a Fahrenheit sign. How could I get rid of these Unicode errors, without fixing it manually the XML file?

For the last line of my code i get this error message
**UnicodeEncodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t encode character u’\xb0’ in position 1267: ordinal not in range(128)**

```
<Fruits>
<Fruit>
    <Family>Citrus</Family>
    <Explanation>They cannot grow at a temperature below 32 °F</Explanation>
    <Type>Orange</Type>
    <Type>Lemon</Type>
    <Type>Lime</Type>
    <Type>Grapefruit</Type>
</Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Can you provide a one-line example XML file the demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Im using Python 2.7. I included an XML example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write, where the error occurs. Probably in the last line. You have to encode the strings yourself:

```
with open('test.csv','w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for f in Fruit:
        explanation = f.findtext("Explanation")
        types = f.findall("Type")
        for t in types:
            a.writerow([t.text.encode('utf8'), explanation.encode('utf8')])
```

Comment: `'\xb0'.decode('latin1') == u'°'` so it's probably `latin1`. `utf8` throws an error.

Comment: `u'\xb0'` is already an unicode string. The error is in **encoding** not **decoding**.

Comment: I edited my code, you can see it above now. You can also see a part of the XML file.

Comment: If you are using python2, you have to encode by hand. See my edit.